# How do Eddy currents follow conservation of energy?

Tags: energy-conservation, electromagnetic-induction, induction

When wind blows, leaves of a tree move and they gain kinetic energy. In this case air molecules loose kinetic energy and transfer it to the leaf.
But In case of eddy currents moving inside a conductor, where do these electrons get their energy from for rotating? What is lost? Does magnet provides them kinetic energy?

Comment: Yes the *changing* magnet field transfers energy to the electrons. See [Faraday's law of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction)

Answer (score 1):

When eddy currents are induced in some way or other the work is done to change the magnetic flux or move a conductor though a magnetic field.
That work done on the system finishes up as ohmic heating in the conductor.

For example a conductor cutting magnetic field lines will have eddy currents produced within it.
With no external sources of energy that conductor will slow down (lose kinetic energy) and that decrease in kinetic energy will be balanced by the conductor being heated.

This conversion of kinetic energy into heat is illustrated in [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MglUIiBy2lQ).

Comment: "With no external sources of energy that conductor will slow down (lose kinetic energy) and that decrease in kinetic energy" electrons kinetic energy? but where does the kinetic energy come from at the first place   "decrease in kinetic energy will be balanced by the conductor being heated." kinetic energy is directly linked to heat , not inversely?

Comment: @quantised The conductor will not spontaneously start to move. Something eg you, will have to do work on the conductor to make it move and hence has some kinetic energy. Remove that source of energy, ie leave the conductor to its own devices, and it will use up its kinetic energy and heat will be produced. In the pendulum video the demonstrator pulled the pendulum to one side giving it he pendulum gravitational potential energy